# `require': cannot load such file - Ruby + Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Im having a trouble with loading dependences in a ruby app (non-rails).

Its folder tree

project

```
  -> bin
  -> lib
    -> modules
      -> file1.rb
      -> file2.rb
  -> spec
    -> file2_spec.rb
```

My file is

```
require 'file1'

module File2
end
```

My spec is

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../lib/modules/file2'
```

In the error message it shows

rspec spec/query_util_spec.rb
/home/gustavo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- **file1** (LoadError)

I tried to add "require_relative" to file1 in my spec and still does not work.

I'll be grateful someone give me some directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking how rspec do this reference stuff in rails, I solved it by add

```
require File.expand_path("path", __FILE__)
```

instead of using require_relative

Answer (score 4):

Change your `File2.rb` to this:

```
require './file1'

module File2
end
```

Comment: It just did not accept require './file1' and broke not only the test but the program itself.

I solved it by, adding require = File.expand_path('path', File.dirname(__FILE__)).

thanks for your efforts, upvoted by give me directions.

Answer (score 2):

When you said `"I tried to add "require_relative" to file1 in my spec and still does not work"` were you talking about file2_spec.rb?

It just looks like you've not got require_relative in File2?

With the following, I get the same as you:

`` $ find -type f
./lib/modules/file1.rb
./lib/modules/file2.rb
./spec/file2_spec.rb
$ cat lib/modules/file1.rb
puts "hello world"
$ cat lib/modules/file2.rb
require 'file1'
$ cat spec/file2_spec.rb
require_relative '../lib/modules/file2'
$ ruby spec/file2_spec.rb
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- file1 (LoadError)
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /apps/stackoverflow/lib/modules/file2.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from spec/file2_spec.rb:1:in `require_relative'
        from spec/file2_spec.rb:1:in `<main>' ``

But with a relative include in file2.rb, it works fine:

`$ cat spec/file2_spec.rb
require_relative '../lib/modules/file2'
$ cat lib/modules/file2.rb
require_relative 'file1'
$ ruby spec/file2_spec.rb
hello world`

That said, if you're looking to create a library, then it's probably worth setting up your LOAD_PATH properly so you don't have to do this everywhere:

`$ cat spec/file2_spec.rb
$LOAD_PATH.unshift("{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../lib/modules")
require 'file2'
$ cat lib/modules/file2.rb
require 'file1'
$ ruby spec/file2_spec.rb
hello world`

(or just setup your environment variables etc)

NB, the use of

`require './file1'`

does a require relative to the working directory, so it's not equivalent to

`require_relative 'file1'`